# Retreive tables having identity column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to retreive in sql server all table name having identity column. Is there any way to do it via a query without looping over all the columns in sys.columns?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. You can query the [sys.identity_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-identity-columns-transact-sql) catalog:

```
select t.name TableName
from sys.tables t
where exists (select 1 from sys.identity_columns where [object_id] = t.[object_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS has a lot of columns of information, like length of column, data type, etc.

In this case, we're using it to pull information about identity columns.

```
select TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 
1 
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Another helpful one is INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to provide a list of tables.